# how to show only one date if all records have same date in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

[image: table]

I want to show the similar dates only once even thought all the columns has the value like in this picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try checkbox suppress if duplicate only for the date field

Comment: This will work, but it should be noted that if the data is not sorted by the date column first, there will be duplicates when a different date appears between two similar dates.

Comment: You are correct. Im not really good in grouping. But you also can try it, for same cases, it will work. Good luck. If grouping is still not working, I would suggest you to use query

Answer (score 0):

Group by Date. The easiest way is just to leave the Group Header visible, which will add a header for that date.

If you must include it as a column instead, keep the grouping, suppress the header and footer, and suppress the date field on this formula:

```
{yourFieldHere} = PREVIOUS({yourFieldHere})
```